# GET variable not working in PHP Script. Theme support days it's a server problem

Tags: php, wordpress, get

I have a php script in a theme which is failing in $_GET variable. Theme Support says this is not their problem and some problem on the server side. The $_GET in your theme and plugins files is not working somehow. I don't know how to troubleshoot this.. can someone please assist?

```
<?php do_action( 'bp_before_course_results' ); ?>

<?php
$user_id=get_current_user_id();

if(isset($_GET['action']) && !is_numeric($_GET['action'])){
                echo '<div id="message"><p>'.__('Invalid Results','vibe').'</p></div>';
}else{

        if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']){ // Check Action
                $id = intval($_GET['action']);
                $post_type = get_post_type($id);
                do_action('wplms_get_'.$post_type.'_result',$id,$user_id);
        }else{ // Show all Results
                do_action('wplms_get_user_results',$user_id);
        }

}
?>
<?php do_action( 'bp_after_course_results' ); ?>
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is in your conditional / if:

`if(isset($_GET['action']) && !is_numeric($_GET['action'])){`

If I'm reading your logic correctly, I believe that should be:

`if(!isset($_GET['action']) || !is_numeric($_GET['action'])){`

Essentially saying, if the `action` param is NOT set OR the `action` param is NOT numeric, then print the Invalid Results message.

Comment: Many thanks for looking.. I checked and found it's working if I use it under Apache2.. fails on nginx.. obviously some configuration issue which I need to look into..